# What year etc is this Specialized Epic Comp?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, specialized-bikes

I'm trying to find what kind of brand/year my bike is so I can find more information about it. It might help me determine if I should buy a new bike or just wait.
The only information I got now is this:
Epic Comp Specialized, but I don't know the year and so on[image: epic comp specialized (but I still need the year and so on]

Comment: Why should the year effect your decision when to buy a new bike?  The component level is the component level.  The condition of the bike is the condition of the bike.  It could be a 6 year old bike in pristine condition and a trashed out bike 6 month old bike.   Looks like a nice bike.  Any components, sizing, or geometry you are not happy with?  Any known defect(s)?

Comment: I just wanna know if Im paying to much for the bike, thats why I wanna know the year etc...anyways thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Then ASK that. You state "I have" like you own it.   And the answer is base it on the condition and components and not age.  On a blue book just base it on latest year with those components.

Comment: The title of this question made it sound like it was a general-purpose "How do I identify a bike?" question, and it's had more than 20,000 hits from people who presumably expected just that. I've edited the title to match the actual question; hopefully, there will be fewer disappointed visitors in future.

Answer (score 4):

The nice people at specialized.com have a archive section with pictures of all the models produced since 2008.  Go to the [web site](http://www.specialized.com/) and scroll down to the bottom of the page. There's a Support section with Bike Archive as the last item.

Answer shamelessly stolen from [here](http://specialized.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/808731-serial-number-lookup).

Answer (score 3):

Likely to be the 2011 model. Both the 2010 and 2012 have significantly different front triangles.

https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=21935